# Moving file between disks in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, hard-drive

Is there any way so when I drag and drop a file from one disk(A) to another disk(B) the files are moved instead of copied? I have a mac book pro and a mac pro(old cool one) and when I drag and drop files they get copied instead of moved. So could I do some automate script or terminal command to enable move files from disk to disk instead of coping them?

Comment: The last sentence says "with in disk" but earlier say one disk to another - what do you mean

Comment: My bad that is a typo, is plural so i can move files from disk to disk that are inside my machines.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[On macOS Mojave 10.14](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/organize-files-in-folders-mh26885/10.14/mac/10.14):

To move files to a different disk: Press and hold the <kbd>Command</kbd> key, then drag the files to the disk.

To keep an item in its original location and put a copy in a folder: Press and hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key, then drag the item to the folder.

In older macOS releases, you could press the <kbd>option</kbd> key to change the behaviour

- move instead of copy between different volumes
- copy instead of move on the same volume

Comment: that works great, didn't knot existed. thanks, but is there any way to always say move instead of copy when the volumes are `/dev/disk2`  &&  `/dev/disk3s2`

Comment: maybe a automator or command like to change the settings in the kernel?

Answer (score 5):

Hold the "Command" key down, not the "option" key, while dragging your file between hard drives.  You will know that you have done it correctly because the progress bar will say "moving" instead of "copying"